# How create a crontab on mac?

Tags: cron, macos

I'm trying to create a crontab on mac.

I've tried [`crontab -e`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212705/302720) which takes me to what appears to be an empty file opened with vim. I make no changes and simply press <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, then <kbd>q</kbd> to save and exit.

But when I try `crontab -l` I see:

```
crontab -l
crontab: no crontab for st
```

I tried exactly the same thing [as root](https://superuser.com/a/540693/928461) but I get the same outcome

```
MacBook-Pro:~ root# crontab -u st -e
crontab: no crontab for st - using an empty one
-- I save an exit vim as above --

crontab: no changes made to crontab
MacBook-Pro:~ root# crontab -u st -l
crontab: no crontab for st
```

I'm struggling to figure out why this isn't working as expected

Comment: Check out this [link](https://medium.com/better-programming/https-medium-com-ratik96-scheduling-jobs-with-crontab-on-macos-add5a8b26c30) about *Crontab on macOS*

Comment: @SwissCodeMen extremely useful, thanks. I have only one question, in `0,15,30,45 * * * * cd ~/.scripts && ./work.sh` what is the purpose of `./` i.e. why not just `work.sh` ?

Comment: ECHO isn't a command - echo is. You can make it write out a test file with: echo $(date) >> /tmp/cron.test

Answer (score 5):

This will indeed open a new crontab in vim (presuming you don't already have one)

```
crontab -e
```

If it creates a new crontab for you, it will start empty, **hit the space bar to add something to the crontab before saving and exiting**

So **TL;DR**

1. `crontab -e` creates a new crontab if you don't already have one
2. If it's a new (empty) crontab, press <kbd>i</kbd> to 'insert' using vim, then press spacebar a few times so it's not empty
3. Save and exit vim by pressing these keys (in order): <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, then <kbd>q</kbd>

Comment: What would be a reason to create an empty crontab consisting of a few space characters?

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I had `$VISUAL` configured to use `Visual Studio Code`. I temporarily overrode it: `VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim`. Then after `crontab -e` it printed `crontab: installing new crontab`. A follow up `crontab -l` printed the saved file.

I'm sure there is a way to use VSCode, but this is a quick workaround.

Comment: Crontab is deprecated. You should be using `launchd` instead

Comment: @allan Crontab has been deprecated for so long that I stopped bothering :-)

Answer (score 1):

A bit more info on the same topic.

To get started:

```sh
# To start editing crontab:
crontab -e

# To list existing:

crontab -l
```

A cron expression is a string of five fields separated by spaces. Each field represents a unit of time:

```sh
*  *  * * *   
│  │  │ │ └───── day of the week (0 - 7, both 0 and 7 represent Sunday)  
│  │  │ └─────── month (1 - 12)  
│  │  └───────── day of the month (1 - 31)  
│  └──────────── hour (0 - 23)  
└─────────────── minute (0 - 59)
```

To create a crontab notation you may use this generator:
https://crontab.guru/

Now, once you have the sequence, in terminal `crontab -e` to start editing.

If it's a new (empty) crontab, press <kbd>i</kbd> to 'insert' using vi editor. Insert the sequence and command for example `* * * * * say minute` to make your Mac say "minute", every minute. Press <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>wq</kbd>, then hit <kbd>return</kbd>.

To delete the crontab entry `crontab -e`, press <kbd>dd</kbd> to 'delete the line' using vi editor. Press <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>wq</kbd>, then hit <kbd>return</kbd>.

Read more:

- https://www.geekbitzone.com/posts/2020/macos/crontab/macos-schedule-tasks-with-crontab/
- https://www.airplane.dev/blog/how-to-edit-crontab